# ggplot2 dodging factor that is not the grouping factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

With this data frame

```
df <- data.frame(y=c(5,5,6,3,3), x=c("A","A","B","C","C"), time=c("T1","T2","T1","T1","T2"),group=c("G1","G1","G1","G2","G2"))

  y x time group
1 5 A   T1    G1
2 5 A   T2    G1
3 6 B   T1    G1
4 3 C   T1    G2
5 3 C   T2    G2
```

is there a way to plot `T1` and `T2` next to each other, when `group` is already the grouping (color) factor?

Basically, it's this plot:

```
ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y,color=group),data=df) + geom_point(size=3)
```

but I'd like to plot two red points dodged at `y=5` when `x=A`, one red point at `y=6` when `x=B` and two red points dodged at `y=3` when `x=C`.

Is that possible with ggplot?

Comment: Have you looked at what using `shape` for `time` and then using `geom_jitter` instead of `geom_point`?

Comment: @Kat, I would rather not use `shape` because in my actual data there are many more time points than just `T1` and `T2`, and the plot gets quite messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `group` aesthetic and `position_dodge`

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = group, group = time)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3, position = position_dodge(0.1))
```

[image]